# How to match input without spaces (must be single word) and with characters/numbers/special characters using regex

Tags: regex, match, space

It's not clear to me how can i check if the username and password are meaningful, so made by single word and with characters/numbers/some special characters.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, `^\S+$`? *1 or more symbols other than whitespace, from the beginning to the end.* What are the actual requirements?

Comment: Actual requirement: classical input for username and password (normal internet forms), that is: no spaces (I want a single word), alphanumerical characters and some special character, probably characters like !,?,_.-, should be allowed either. 
The Shapiro's and stribizhev answers seems not to work.
Thanks!

Comment: Mmm sorry the stribizhev string seems to work. 
In the end works quite fine this:
Dim Check_spaces1 As Boolean = Regex.IsMatch(TextBox01.Text, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
Only some standard (widely used probably) subset of "special character" is still missing...